# Change in state not displaying in console log

Tags: reactjs, state

I am building a simple timer app and keeping track of elapsed time in state using hooks. I know I am setting state correctly because it displays in the app every passing second. However, when I console log `elapsedTime`, it repeatedly logs the initial state (0 in this case):

```js
const Timer = () => {
  const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = React.useState(0);

  const handleStart = () => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval(() => {
      const et = Math.floor((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
      setElapsedTime(et);
      console.log(elapsedTime);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    clearInterval();
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='timer'>
        <div className='title'></div>
        <div className='time'>{elapsedTime}</div>
        <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Why is my change in state not being reflected in the `console.log` I call on line 9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: *Aside:* Your code doesn't stop the timer. And weird things start to happen when one tries to start another timer while one is already active. :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm trying to figure that out right now lol how would you go about stopping the timer?

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid adding questions to an existing one. If you encounter another problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous, you won't see the changes in the scope of the function

If you want to see the new values at the place where you put the `console.log` you can only do  `console.log(et);`

You can also use a `useEffect` to see the changes of the variable in the console

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("elapsedTime", elapsedTime);
}, [elapsedTime]);
```

Comment: Something I use all the time is: console.log({elapsedTime}); Try it out, you will love it :D No need to write the variable name in clear text when logging it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of javascript clojure, `elapsedTime` on line 9 will always reference the value it had when the function was created.

Answer (score 0):

> how would you go about stopping the timer?

You have to have a reference to the timer you're creating so that you can stop it. A call to `setInverval` returns such a reference (a unique ID).

Then you have to make sure you only have a single timer running at any point in time.

Borrowing Marc Charpentier's answer, your working version of the code could look like this:

```js
const Timer = () => {
  const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [timerId, setTimerId] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("elapsedTime", elapsedTime);
  }, [elapsedTime]);

  const handleStart = () => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    if (timerId === undefined) { // make sure that a timer is not already running
      setTimerId(
        setInterval(() => {
          const et = Math.floor((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
          setElapsedTime(et);
        }, 1000)
      );
    }
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    setTimerId(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='timer'>
        <div className='title'></div>
        <div className='time'>{elapsedTime}</div>
        <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```